# How to install Jade language support in Atom

Tags: node.js, pug, atom-editor

I am using Atom and I would like to create all my new apps with it. However, I notice Atom doesn't have support for Jade. I was googling and all I understood is about a package.

https://atom.io/packages/atom-jade

which is

"Originally converted from the Jade TextMate bundle and adapted for Atom."

But, I have no idea how to get it installed. Also, I can't see anything related with how to do that neither on its github project nor anywhere else.

Debian or similar

I appreciate any help. Thx

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

Go to **File** -> **Settings** -> **+ Install** -> Search for the atom-jade package -> Click **Install**.

If you have terminal access you can also do:

`apm install atom-jade`

Comment: is `atom-jade` preferred over `language-jade` ?

Answer (score 4):

For Atom 1.0.0: `Packages > Settings View > Install Packages/Themes` or `Atom > Preferences > +Install` (for Mac).

Then choose packages: `atom-jade` or `language-jade`.